# AWS Accessing Redshift in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl, aws-glue

I am trying to ETL data from a Redshift instance (in a VPC)  to a S3 bucket using AWS Glue. For this I created a JDBC connection with Redshift.

The crawler successfully fetches schema information from Redshift to data catalog. But when I run the ETL job it fails to fetch data and says "resource unavailable"

1. Do I need to configure a NAT for Glue to connect to Redshift? 
   (Currently it doesn't have a NAT)
2. How crawler was able to read schema information from Redshift even without a NAT?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift is inside your VPC.  Glue is inside your VPC.  S3 isn't.  Accessing S3, by default, in most cases, requires access to the Internet.

To access data in S3, you need either a NAT Gatway, a NAT Instance, or an [S3 VPC Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html) to bring a termination point for S3 traffic inside the VPC.

Comment: I had already configured an S3 VPC endpoint. What confuses me is that, why ETL job fails when the crawler is able to read schema information from redshift? I can't even see cloudwatch logs because they are not being created. However when I ran the sample Glue tutorial that ETL data from S3 to S3, it runs successfully and even creates the logs. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's not clear what you might be missing.  Security group settings, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is still an ongoing issue, for anyone coming across this issue. For my setup it was the availability zone the RDS connection's subnet was in, but as I understand it, this applies to any of the connection types.

The "fix" was to:

1. AWS Console > Glue > Connections > Edit Connection > See which subnet the connection is using.
2. AWS Console > VPC > Subnets >  Identify (or create) a subnet in a different zone.
3. AWS Console > Glue > Connections > Edit Connection > Switch to use the subnet from step 2.
4. Run job.

If the job still fails with Resource Unavailable, repeat until it works.